# How to right align Toggles

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way to make these two `Toggle`s right aligned without expansion in the same way that the `Text`s are?

[image: screenshot]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List() {
            HStack() {
                Label("Label", systemImage: "circle")
                    .frame(alignment: .leading)

                Spacer()
                
                Text("1")
                .frame(alignment: .trailing)
                .background(.red)
                
                Text("2")
                .frame(alignment: .trailing)
                .background(.green)
            }
            
            HStack() {
                Label("Label", systemImage: "circle")
                    .frame(alignment: .leading)

                Spacer()
                
                Toggle("", isOn: Binding(
                    get: { return false },
                    set: {_,_ in }))
                .frame(alignment: .trailing)
                .background(.red)
                
                Toggle("", isOn: Binding(
                    get: { return false },
                    set: {_,_ in }))
                .frame(alignment: .trailing)
                .background(.green)
            }
        }
    }
}

@main
struct TestAppApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add [`fixedSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fixedsize()) to the toggles to prevent them from resizing/stretching out. `fixedSize` fixes their sizes to their ideal size.

```
HStack() {
    Label("Label", systemImage: "circle")
        .frame(alignment: .leading)

    Spacer()
    
    Toggle("", isOn: .constant(false))
    .background(.red)
    .fixedSize()
    
    Toggle("", isOn: .constant(false))
    .background(.green)
    .fixedSize()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set a fixed size for these toggles like below. You also need to handle the toggle state.

```swift
@State var toggleOn = false
...
Toggle("", isOn: $toggleOn)
    .frame(width: 60) //or .fixedSize()
    .background(.red)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works, but I think the other answer is more maintainable.